# UI Tests Xamarin app : System.Exception : Java Development Kit (JDK) not found

Tags: java, xamarin, uitest

I set my path to my JDK.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jeq21.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgX01.png)

But i have this message :
Message:
System.Exception : Java Development Kit (JDK) not found. Please make sure that it is installed and if it's still not located, please set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the directory.

```
Searched locations:Windows Registry
 [ Source: JAVA_HOME ]
```

When i try to use this :

```
public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
{
    if (platform == Platform.Android)
    {
        return ConfigureApp.Android
                .ApkFile("../JhipsterXamarin/JhipsterXamarin.Android/bin/Debug/com.companyname.jhipsterxamarin.apk")
                .StartApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

From the shared screenshot, you are using the custom downloaded **JDK**, not the downloaded **JDK** from Visual Studio.

Maybe the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271` can work when Visual Studio debug the project, however not works for UItest.

Therefore, you could have a try with the generated path from Visual Studio:

`C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25`

Screenshot of my local site:

[image]